# how to toggle airplane mode using WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission?

Tags: android

I want to toggle airplane mode programmatically. I build android app that could be installed as system app. Pleas give me some hints to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, it is not possible to change airplane mode from code as of 4.2 as system settings became read only. See: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html

The documentation for `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` also says that it is not for third party apps, suggesting it is only for apps packaged with the system.